yarn add --dev @chainlink/contracts showing error :Permission denied Publickey
**While running yarn add --dev @chainlink/contracts it shows error : Permissions denied: Public Key
Error:

Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads ssh://git@github.com/ricmoo/ens-normalize.js.git
Directory: /Users/vatsalsharma/hardhat-fund-me-fcc/hardhat-fund-me-fcc
Output:
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

error image
hii could you tell what is the error here?
i tried running the npm command it showed incompatible peer dependecies.

The error message looks like there are some issues with fetching the package from github so there could be some issues with authentication. Did you encounter this issue only with @chainlink/contracts package or similar error also occurs in different packages? I think you should try setting up your SSH key on your machine if you haven't already.
